# How to move data from one slice of structs to another?

Tags: go

I have two structs:

```
type A struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
    Field3 int
}
type B struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
}
```

I want to convert a slice of []A data(`aData`) to a slice of []B data (`bData`).

What is the idiomatic way to do so?

What I tried is [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Q0ZXEba4N5):

```
var newItem B
var aData []A   
var bData []B


aData = [{"bob", 3, 4}, {"mary", 5, 2}] 


for i:=0 ; i < len(aData); i++ {

    newItem = {aData[i].Field1, aData[i].Field2}
    bData = append( bData, newItem )
}
```

But it gives:

> syntax error: missing operand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your code is invalid.  You need a valid array expression for your `aData` declaration, and you need to specify the type when assigning to `bData`.

```
aData := []A{{"bob", 3, 4}, {"mary", 5, 2}}
bData := make([]B, len(aData))

for i, aItem := range aData {
    bData[i] = B{
        Field1: aItem.Field1,
        Field2: aItem.Field2,
    }
}
```

So aside from your syntax errors, this is more idiomatic because:

1. It uses `range` instead of a `for` loop, which is perfect for iterating over an array, and more readable.
2. `bData` is preallocated to the exact size needed.
3. Field names are specified in the declaration of `bData`'s values.  It would be more idiomatic to do the same for `aData` as well, but it gets a bit verbose.